# ChartsNew.js php json Integration

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I searched with google and checked in the forum for an answer, but I couldn't find one.

My Problem is that I want to use ChartsNew.js in combination with php and the datasets should be available for js over json but I get an undefined dataset exception or the chart without contend.

I can convert the php array with the data that I took from the [example](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/blob/master/Samples/StackedBar_with_line.html) from the github project ChartsNew.js. And when I compare the two strings. They are almost the same but the key words are under quotes. I tried it with copying that string into the html file, and the chart worked.

But when I use Javascript to parse the string it tells me the dataset is undefined or it shows the chart without the contend.

I made my variable to an object and the datasets to but it didn't fix the problem.

I found out that the mydata1 has no data when I want to access it in the end. How do I get the var parsing to work properly?

The PHP code:

```
 $data = array(
            'labels' => array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
           'datasets' => array(
                array(
                    'fillColor' => "blue",
                    'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff",
                    'data' => array(100, 200, 400, 2000, 4000, 16000, 20000, 32000, 45000, 85000, 95000, 115000),
                    'title' => "previous Month"
                ),
                array(
                    'fillColor' => "red",
                    'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff",
                    'data' => array(100, 200, 1600, 2000, 12000, 4000, 12000, 13000, 40000, 10000, 20000, 17000),
                    'title' => "current month"
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => "Line",
                    //          fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                    'strokeColor' => "green",
                    'pointColor' => "green",
                    'pointStrokeColor' => "green",
                    'data' => array(200, 400, 2000, 4000, 16000, 20000, 32000, 45000, 85000, 95000, 115000, 132000),
                    'title' => "total"
                )
            )
        );

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        echo '[' . json_encode($data) . ']';
        //echo json_encode($data);
        exit("");
```

... and the output:

```
[{"fillColor":"blue","strokeColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)","pointColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)","pointStrokeColor":"#fff","data":[100,200,400,2000,4000,16000,20000,32000,45000,85000,95000,115000],"title":"previous Month"},{"fillColor":"red","strokeColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)","pointColor":"rgba(220,220,220,1)","pointStrokeColor":"#fff","data":[100,200,1600,2000,12000,4000,12000,13000,40000,10000,20000,17000],"title":"current month"},{"type":"Line","strokeColor":"green","pointColor":"green","pointStrokeColor":"green","data":[200,400,2000,4000,16000,20000,32000,45000,85000,95000,115000,132000],"title":"total"}]
```

... and the HTML code + the original dataset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Customers</h1>
        <div id="id01"></div>

        <script src='ChartNew.js-master/ChartNew.js'></script>
        <script>
            var original_data = {
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        fillColor: "blue",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        data: [100, 200, 400, 2000, 4000, 16000, 20000, 32000, 45000, 85000, 95000, 115000],
                        title: "previous Month"
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor: "red",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        data: [100, 200, 1600, 2000, 12000, 4000, 12000, 13000, 40000, 10000, 20000, 17000],
                        title: "current month"
                    },
                    {
                        type: "Line",
                        strokeColor: "green",
                        pointColor: "green",
                        pointStrokeColor: "green",
                        data: [200, 400, 2000, 4000, 16000, 20000, 32000, 45000, 85000, 95000, 115000, 132000],
                        title: "total"
                    }
                ]
            }

            var newopts = {
                animation: true,
                datasetFill: false,
                canvasBorders: true,
                canvasBordersWidth: 3,
                canvasBordersColor: "black",
                graphTitle: "Graph Title",
                graphTitleFontFamily: "'Arial'",
                graphTitleFontSize: 24,
                graphTitleFontStyle: "bold",
                graphTitleFontColor: "#666",
                legend: true,
                legendBlockSize: 30,
                bezierCurveTension: 0.2,
                legendPosX: 2,
                legendPosY: 0,
                graphMax: 160000,
                yAxisMinimumInterval: 40000,
                scaleXGridLinesStep: 9999
            }

        </script>

        <div id="canvas_parent_id" >
            <canvas id="canvas_stackedbar_id" width="500px" height="500px">Please enable Javascript to see the Chart</canvas>
            <script>

                var mydata1 = new Object();
                mydata1.datasets = new Object();
                    try {
                        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        var url = "http://localhost/file.php?json=123";

                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                        xmlhttp.send();

                        function myFunction(response) {
                            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
                            arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
                            mydata1 = arr;

                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert("Error: " + e);
                    }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Full code will work fine with you

HTML side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://fvancop.github.io/ChartNew.js/ChartNew.js'></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="1000"></canvas>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/file.php?json=123",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (response)
                {
                    new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(response);
                }
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Side

```
$data = array();

$data['labels'] = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
$data['datasets'] = array(
    array(
        'fillColor' => "blue",
        'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff",
        'data' => array(100, 200, 400, 2000, 4000, 16000, 20000, 32000, 45000, 85000, 95000, 115000),
        'title' => "previous Month"
    ),
    array(
        'fillColor' => "red",
        'strokeColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        'pointColor' => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        'pointStrokeColor' => "#fff",
        'data' => array(100, 200, 1600, 2000, 12000, 4000, 12000, 13000, 40000, 10000, 20000, 17000),
        'title' => "current month"
    ),
    array(
        'type' => "Line",
        //          fillColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        'strokeColor' => "green",
        'pointColor' => "green",
        'pointStrokeColor' => "green",
        'data' => array(200, 400, 2000, 4000, 16000, 20000, 32000, 45000, 85000, 95000, 115000, 132000),
        'title' => "total"
    )
);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($data);
//echo json_encode($data);
exit("");
```

Comment: I was edit post to full code will work fine with you